# node js url mapping

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have two api end points. Both are given below. When I do these below axios requests, both the time first api gets triggered. can anyone tell me how the mapping is done here?

```
1. router.get('/api/posts/user/:id', (req, res)
2. router.get('/api/posts/:tag', (req, res)

1. axios
     .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/posts/user/${id}`)
2. axios
     .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/posts/${tag}`)
```

Comment: How is express supposed to distinguish between `user` and any other value of `:tag`? It seems like you're *searching* for specific posts, this would make more sense as query than path parameters, e.g. `/api/posts?tag=...`.

Comment: mean sending the params thing as a http body?

Comment: No, I mean doing what I showed in the comment above, putting query parameters in the URL.

Comment: /api/posts?tag=..., here tag is variable. Can you tell me how to write the route here?

Comment: The route is still `/api/posts`. Please do some research on query parameters in Express.

Comment: @Sujoy these routes should work. Your problem is elsewhere

Comment: nope. jonsharpe was right.@mihai